# PostgreSQL monitoring With Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

In Zabbix, what is the possibility to monitor many postgres databases .
because only one server database can be defined in odbc.ini

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the zabbix share site [here](https://share.zabbix.com/databases/db_postgresql), you will see several templates which provide for monitoring via the zabbix agent.  By using the zabbix agent instead of the server side odbc option, you push the actual connectivity out to the agent (which could, of course, be on the same server as zabbix). This allows you to do separate discovery and even separate credentials for each server (e.g. in user macros).

I did not experiment with the templates present there, merely offer them as examples. Determining what exactly one monitors on a database is the more difficult subject, of course, since it can be highly variable by site -- what is "normal" at that site, and so what is worthy of an alert. But with LLD and ability to do arbitrary queries, you can form any items and triggers you may need.  Effectively you can have your DBA (might be you also of course) craft the criteria, and just put it wholesale into the template.